# how perf record get the virtual memory address of instruction of the target process and what data struct does perf use to store it

Tags: c, linux, perf

I'm reading source code of perf and try to make sense of how `perf record` get the the virtual memory address of an Instruction of the target process that trigger perf to count(for example the virtual address of `call test`,which is assembly code watched by `perf report`'s annotation). And what data structure does perf use to store the virtual address of the instruction that make perf-event happen and trigger counter?

Comment: On what level do you want the answer? Are you interested in the `perf record` userland tool, the `perf_event_open` implementation in the kernel?

Comment: I want to get and print virtual address of instruction that trigger hardware counter. Specially, there is an instruction will make TSX abort, and perf naive event `tx-abort` will be counted by hardware counter. When `perf report`, I can watch it by `perf annotation` the intruction. So I want to know when run `perf record` ,what data structure store virtual address of that instruction. Or do you know how perf_event_open can achieve this?

Comment: Do you just want to get an analysis done? Then you should use `perf record` / `perf script`, and read their manpages. Or do you want to write a specific tool? Then why? What should this new tool based on `perf_event_open` do that `perf record` can't?

Comment: Yeah, I want to write a specific tools. I have read the manual of perf_event_open, but too few examples still confused me. How can perf_event_open get the `tx-abort` event counter and virtual address of instruction trigger `tx-abort`?

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the instruction pointers for samples, you must include `PERF_SAMPLE_IP` in `perf_attr.sample_type` for the `perf_event_open` call. This will include the `ip` field in the struct for `PERF_RECORD_SAMPLE` events that you can read from the `mmap` ringbuffer. See the manpage for details.

```
PERF_RECORD_SAMPLE
    This record indicates a sample.

       struct {
            struct perf_event_header header;
            u64    sample_id;   /* if PERF_SAMPLE_IDENTIFIER */
            u64    ip;          /* if PERF_SAMPLE_IP */
            u32    pid, tid;    /* if PERF_SAMPLE_TID */
            u64    time;        /* if PERF_SAMPLE_TIME */
            ...
```